# Html mathjax mathbb does not work

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I import mathjax into my html file via

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
          config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
          jax: ["input/TeX","input/MathML","input/AsciiMath","output/HTML-CSS","output/NativeMML", "output/PreviewHTML"],
          extensions: ["tex2jax.js","mml2jax.js","asciimath2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js", "fast-preview.js", "AssistiveMML.js", "a11y/accessibility-menu.js"],
          TeX: {
            extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]
          }
        });
</script>
```

and still `$\mathbb{R}$` causes `Unexpected text node: ''` in the browser (Chrome).

I checked on [MathJax.org](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html) that `\mathbb` should work after importing the TeX extension AMSsymbols.js.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might want to post a live example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: The unexpected text node error comes from MathML input, not TeX input, so I'm wondering if you have some `<math>` nodes that are causing the problem.  Try removing the `mml2jax.js` and `asciimath2jax.js` and see if the error goes away.  Also, note that dollar-sign delimiters are off by default, so unless you also include `TeX: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]} in your configuration, MathJax probably isn't even processing the `$\mathbb{R}$` at all.